# How to efficiently deploy Wordpress on local, test and production

Tags: wordpress, deployment

We have a large multi language Wordpress website. We have 3 servers. We develop local, then test it on a test server. Then the customer tests in on a "acceptation" server and after the "OK" it goes to a production server.

My question now is:

If for example I delete and -or install a couple of plugins, I currently have to do it four times. Locally, and on every server.

Is there a way where we can just do everything locally and then push it to GIT and GIT wil handle it for us on any other server we push it to?

And even if this is possible... we work with anonymized data on all servers except the production server meaning we cannot just 1:1 copy the database to the production database.

I hope you can share your experience on how to handle this properly.

We use Homestead, Jenkins and Github by the way :)

Write code, install plugins et cetera one time, and be able to push it to git so it will be merged with any server (test, accept or production) without having to i.e. install plugins manually on each server. Also the database should be updated structure wise, we do not want to overwrite the "product server" their information obviously. But for a table that holds the "plugins" we do want to overwrite it. Difficult story I guess.

We looked at a couple of plugins i.e. https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/ and https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/ but that is obviously a plugin and not an automated process you can do with Jenkins.

Comment: The migrations has a lot to do with Database? or only code?

Comment: Migrations are database wise :) anything that can be overwritten may be overwritten but stuff like "posts" and "users" et cetera should never be overwritten.